# Случай 3-х колонночного макета

Tags: html, css

Привет. Нужен каркас, как разместить 3 блока.

Первый и третий блок- динаммчески изменяющиеся (не в %). Нужен средний блок, который будет сжиматься, если крайние блоки увеличиваются.

Нужно без js.

Каждый из блоков имеет свой min-width.
Думал объединить 2 блока в один...

Comment: ваши наработки?

Comment: я похож на шаровика? Какой нароботок тебе показать.3 div без стилей?

Answer (score 1):

Задача сформулирована очень не ясно, но если я правильно понял, то можно так http://jsfiddle.net/cBBsF/

Comment: у тебе верстка расваливается при ресайзе.У тебя ширина блоков фиксированая.

Comment: Смотрим сюда http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-trekhkolonochnyi-maket и мне нужен случай когда 3 колонки каждая   занимает оставшееся пространство(знак бесконечности (∞))

Comment: Во-первых, при ресайзе ничего не разваливается. Если только у вас экран монитора на пикселей 300. А что тебе мешает поставить проценты, если фиксированная не нравится?

Во-вторых, как три колонки могут занимать оставшееся место если их всего 3? Оставшееся место от чего?

Сделай их по 33.33(3)% и радуйся.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то задам вопрос, а не пробовали средний блок, который должен растягиваться и сжиматься в зависимости от размера соседей, указать его width в %? И пусть себе сжимается) С примером сложновато, могу только посоветовать поковыряться в HTML коде здесь originalip.ru смысл абсолютно тот же, только в вашем случае размеры левого и правого блока меняться будут, а в моём они статичны. 
Как вариант, можно и таблицами сделать, метод устарел, но как вариант) 
Вот ещё вариант, привожу цитату со статьи 
"Давайте посмотрим на первую строку, [[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) all and (min-width: 650px), этим мы сообщаем браузеру, в случае если ширина дисплея шире чем 650px, то отображаем колонки с изображениями продуктов рядом, если меньше, то они будут располагаться одна за другой"
[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) all and (min-width: 650px){
    здесь ваш стиль для среднего блока
}

Comment: Нельзя указать жестко ширину в %.(например 40%).Если было можно,то есть уже решение.Решение есть,через таблици с хаком,но не хочется его использовать

Comment: И не указывайте жёстко, пусть сама ресайзится, укажите только минимум. ведь это и есть решение... или максимум... иначе, либо php либо js